# Uso de una clase importada para la creacion de una clase

Tags: java

necesito ayuda en lo siguiente:

Crear la clase Pagare. La clase contiene campos de datos que guardan un número de pagaré, apellido paterno del cuentahabiente, monto, fecha de apertura y fecha de vencimiento, usar objetos GregorianCalendar para cada fecha. Proporcionar métodos accesores y mutadores para cada campo. También proporcionar un constructor que requiera parámetros para poner los primeros cuatro campos, y calcule la fecha de vencimiento un año después de la fecha de apertura.
La clase GregorianCalendar es útil cuando se trabaja con fechas y tiempos. Tiene siete constructores disponibles para crear objetos. El método de instancia get con diferentes constantes devuelve información relativa a la fecha, como el año, o el mes. Consultar la documentación para mayor información.

En lo unico que necesito ayuda es al momento del uso de la clase GregorianCalendar, si me pudieran ayudar en esa cuestion se los agradeceria, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Pudes ser un poco más específico en lo que necesitas.
Entre tanto, este ejemplo te puede servir.

https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=619:clase-calendar-y-gregoriancalendar-java-conversion-de-fechas-ejemplos-cambios-desde-java-8-cu00925c&catid=58&Itemid=180

Comment: Bueno, esencialmente lo que yo busco es saber como a partir del Scanner asignar los valores de la fecha por medio de la clase GregorianCalendar, eso resolveria todas mis dudas y ya he investigado pero no encuentro nada